# Trying to shorten this block of code as much as possible using code golfing etc

Tags: powershell

I have the following fun little script used to have a user automatically subscribe to a youtube channel, just trying to see how far someone can dwindle this code down

Ex: using `-AssemblyName *m.W*s.F*s` instead of `-AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
$o=New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;
Saps https://www.youtube.com/CHANNEL-NAME?sub_confirmation=1;
Sleep 3;
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{TAB}'*2);
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}');
Sleep 1;
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{F4}')
```

Comment: Certainly, this can be shortened, but if the plan is to have someone else support this after you or you plan to share it, then the shortening is just going to make it harder on folks in those use cases. The common/accepted/best practice is not to use shorthand in scripts, especially production scripts. Using shorthand for ad-hoc keyboard stuff and throwaway code, then shorthand is the thing. Imagine reading any reference or guidance doc that was all in someone's special shorthand, and them expecting you to understand it. Just, say'n.

Comment: You are 100% correct, but this is indeed basically throw away code for my personal use. I'm not a monster lol

Comment: ***;-}*** No worries. I use tons of shorthand, all the time, but like you, that's specifically for my use. If I share it, I expand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut `-AssemblyName` to `-a`, as long as the prefix is unique it will match.

On mine `s*ms` matches only System.Windows.Forms.

You could cut `-ComObject` to the shortest unique prefix `-c`, but you aren't using the WScript.Shell object so drop that line.

Drop `www.` from the YouTube URL

Merge the two Tabs and Enter to remove one of the SendWait lines.

Drop `[System.` from the type names.

Store the SendKeys bit for reuse shorter.

I've dropped the `;` but they need to come back for it to be on one line.

```
add-type -a s*ms
saps https://youtube.com/CHANNEL-NAME?sub_confirmation=1
($w=[Windows.Forms.SendKeys])::SendWait('{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}')
sleep 1
$w::SendWait('%{F4}')
```

I think that's as short as it easily gets, it's possible to store `SendWait` as well, but then you need `.Invoke()` which pads it out again. There's no default aliases for `add-type` or `new-object`.

If you could swap for WScript.Shell SendKeys, can use `|%` to invoke a method by a pattern:

```
$w=New-Object -c wscript.shell
saps https://youtube.com/CHANNEL-NAME?sub_confirmation=1
$w|% s*s '{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}'
sleep 1
$w|% s*s '%{F4}'
```